# Git project owner accept others changes before pushing to branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm a new user to gitlab. I want to check and code review all of the changes that anyone committed before pushing to the branch. is it possible in gitlab? if yes how can I do it? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any git/gitlab/bitbucket yes you can do it.

1. Protect access to master branch.

[image]

2. Others should create a branch and raise a pull request to merge into master.
3. You should/can add yourself/someone as default reviewer.
4. Now you can merge whichever branch/pull request you want if it fulfills your reviewing criteria.
5. Best case is make sure except you none are in admin role.

Comment: how can I accept/refuse the committed change? my point is if it is ok, I push it to branch

Comment: You can accept/refuse pull requests, not commits. If you need commits too refusable then at-most code compile/testing can be done on `gitlab pipeline` which will decline pull request merging. Other way is testing with `git hooks precommit`. Hooks should be at user's system. So that before every commit code is tested.

Comment: Its ok to push it to a branch, but not merge to a branch which you will use for production. lets take `development` branch is cluttered, and pullrequest is raised to `master`. you can always decline pull request and give review comments.